# where can I find documentation of r2dbc metrics?

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

Where can I find in depth descriptions of the r2dbc metrics?

Specifically I try to understand what exactly these represent:

```
r2dbc_pool_acquired_connections
r2dbc_pool_allocated_connections
r2dbc_pool_idle_connections
r2dbc_pool_max_allocated_connections
r2dbc_pool_max_pending_connections
r2dbc_pool_pending_connections
```

Comment: Did you look at Actuator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more information I found in the description of **io.r2dbc.pool.PoolMetrics** interface. Example link:
https://javadoc.io/static/io.r2dbc/r2dbc-pool/0.9.0.M1/io/r2dbc/pool/PoolMetrics.html